# Intermittent results when merging images

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, dom-events

I'm having a lot of trouble using event code with my procedural code. I have a function the merges images and it's being called 20-40 times per second. Some times it works and sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes `drawImage` is called before the image has loaded, sometimes it isn't. Here's the code (it's a method of a class):

```
merge(image, pos) {
  if (!pos && !image.pos)
    pos = [0, 0];
  else if (!pos)
    pos = image.pos;

  canvas.element[3].width = this.width;
  canvas.element[4].width = this.width;
  canvas.element[3].height = this.height;
  canvas.element[4].height = this.height;

  canvas.ctx[3].putImageData(this.toImageData(), ...this.pos);
  var image1 = new Image(this.width, this.height);
  image1.onload = function() {/*help pls*/};
  image1.src = canvas.element[3].toDataURL();
  canvas.ctx[4].drawImage(image1, 0, 0);

  canvas.ctx[3].clearRect(0,0,this.width,this.height);

  canvas.ctx[3].putImageData(image.toImageData(), ...pos);
  image1 = new Image(this.width, this.height);
  image1.onload = function() {/*help pls*/};
  image1.src = canvas.element[3].toDataURL();
  canvas.ctx[4].drawImage(image1, 0, 0);

  this.data.set(new Uint32Array(canvas.ctx[4].getImageData(0,0,this.width,this.height).data.buffer));
  return this;
}
```

I know that I must write something in `onload` event. I feel like I've tried everything. I want function to "seem" procedural to the caller. This function will be called, it will do it's thing and return the result. I don't want to input a callback and turn all my nice simple procedural code into event code.

I tried using a while loop to "wait" for the `onload` event to fire but that didn't work (I hate while loops!). All it did was crash! I tried putting everything that followed into the `onload` event but I had no way of returning `this` immediately after it had been altered.

I think I read somewhere that you could use a recursive loop. I vaguely remember `arguments.callee`. But I don't how to implement this.

Comment: That won't answer your actual question, but did you know that you can directly draw a canvas onto an other one with drawImage() ? No need to load the dataURL version into an img.

Comment: OMG! That does answer the question! No need for events, I could just draw the canvas. Thank you so much!

Comment: glad it solved your issue but it doesn't answer your question. @Blindman67's answer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Javascript is sequential"

An important thing to know when writing event driven code in javascript is that code execution in javascript is strictly sequential. One function at a time, one instruction in order at a time. You can not interrupt the execution of javascript.

When you write something like

```
function doSomething(){
     var img = new Image();
     img.onload = function(){ // do stuff }; // This can not run until
                                             // your current call is over.
     img.src = "foo.img";
     // lots more code..
     ...
     ...
     ...
     // end of the function
}

//code
doSomething();
// more code.

console.log("Have a nice day"); // last line

// at this point there is no more code
// so javascript returns 
// then it checks if there is anything on the call stack.
// It is only now that onload can run.
```

When you call `doSomething` that function will block all other javascript. You can call functions, but no async events will execute until you have exited `doSomething`.

That means the the `onload` event must wait until the `doSomething` function has returned. More precisely that the call is empty (no more returns), so if you start with `foo()` calling `bar()`, calling `baf()`. It is not until `foo()` has returned and all the code below it has finished that any other code can run.

The image loading is async, it is loaded on a separate thread. When it has finished loading it does not call the function `onload`, instead it places the call on the call stack. There is only one call stack and the order of calls placed on it by native async calls like image loading, timeout, interval, etc is dependent on when the async is done.

What is happening in your code is that the image you create is being replaced by the new image that you assign the original image variable. As there is no reference to the original image and as the onload can not happen till you exit, javascript assumes you no longer need the first image and dumps it.

There are several ways to fix the problem. One is to ensure that a reference to each new image is maintained. You can do this with `image.addEventListener("load", function(){ //your image is "this'});` This will maintain a reference to the original image because the event listener is stored separately from the image, unlike `image.onload = function(){}` which is lost along with the image when you assign a new image to that variable.

Another way is to use closure to hold a reference to the image.

```
function doSomething(){
    var img;   

    // when the following function is call the argument
    // image is closed over. This means that it keeps an unique 
    // reference to image every time this function is call.
    // this means that the image is not replaced below
    function addEvent(image){  
        image.onload = function(){}
    }

    img = new Image()
    img.src = "blah.img"
    addEvent(img);  // use function closure to close over the image
                    // thereby maintaining a separate reference to the img

    img = new Image(); // replace the previous image with new
    img.src = "blah1.img"; // because the addEvent function has closed over
                           // the previous img and is holding a separate reference
                           // the image will not be dumped
    addEvent(img); // clos over this one making a second reference via closure

}

doSomething();
// not until completely exited that the onload functions can be removed from the
// call stack and executed.
```

The simplest way is to create individual references yourself.

```
var imageArray = [];
function doSomething(){
    img = new Image()
    img.src = "blah.img"
    img.onload = function(){};
    imageArray.push(img);  // copy the image reference to the array.

    img = new Image();  // create a new image but the previous one
    img.src = "blah.img"  // is still referenced and thus wont be lost.
    img.onload = function(){};
    imageArray.push(img);  // copy the image reference to the array.
}
```

Doing it this way may help get your head around it a little clearer, but all three methods do the same thing. They create a separate reference to the image, storing a copy of the image reference one for each image. Allowing the images to exist until the current execution returns and the onload events can be fired.

Using the array will of course fill memory with images unless you remove the image reference from the array. But that is another story.

hope that explains what is going wrong with your code and gives you what yu need to modify your code and continue the fun part of coding, rather than the frustrating part.